# Azure Function return multiple JSON objects

Tags: c#, json, azure, azure-functions

This is my azure function app.

```
#r "System.Configuration"
#r "System.Data"
using System.Net;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, 
TraceWriter log)
{       
    int num;    
    string query = req.GetQueryNameValuePairs()
        .FirstOrDefault(q => string.Compare(q.Key, "num", true) == 0)
        .Value;    

    if (query == null)
    {
        // Get request body
        dynamic data = await req.Content.ReadAsAsync<object>();
        num = data.num;
    }
    else {
        num = Convert.ToInt32(query);
    }      

    int[] numRead = new int[3];
    string[] nameRead = new string[3];    

    var str = 
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sqldb_connection"].ConnectionString;

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(str))
    {
        conn.Open();
        var text = "select num,name from bus where num=@num;";

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(text, conn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@num", num);
            using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) 
            {
                int i = 0;
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    numRead[i] = reader.GetInt32(0);                    
                    nameRead[i++] = reader.GetString(1);
                    Console.WriteLine(numRead[i] + ":" + nameRead[i]);                    
                }
            }
        }        
    }
    return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new {            
        name = nameRead[0],
        num = numRead[0]           
    });    
}
```

I want the function to return multiple json like this

```
return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new {
        "item1" : {
            name = nameRead[0],
            num = numRead[0]
        },
        "item2" : {
            name = nameRead[1],
            num = numRead[1]
        },
        "item3" : {
            name = nameRead[2],
            num = numRead[2]
        }
    });
```

but it doesn't work.

C# has `JsonArray`, `JsonObject` or `JsonValue` class, but I don't understand how to use them and don't know the difference between them.

Comment: Why not create an object which has name and num, make a list, and return that array?

Comment: Create object(s) for your data using a website such as this one - http://json2csharp.com/  You can then serialise the data to Json using Json.NET to achieve the desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work if you make it valid C#:

```cs
return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new {
    item1 = new {
        name = nameRead[0],
        num = numRead[0]
    },
    item2 = new {
        name = nameRead[1],
        num = numRead[1]
    },
    item3 = new {
        name = nameRead[2],
        num = numRead[2]
    }
});
```

Comment: No overload for method 'CreateResponse' takes 2 arguments

Comment: @Neo This answer applies to v1 version of Functions (as was the question about)

Answer (score 1):

You can just return an array of your instances and the framework will take care of the conversion to JSON.

First you create a class to hold your items:

```
public class Result
{
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public int Num {get; set;}
}
```

And now you just return an array of these:

```
return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new Result[] {
        new Result() {
            Name = nameRead[0],
            Num = numRead[0]
        },
        new Result() {
            Name = nameRead[1],
            Num = numRead[1]
        },
        new Result() {
            Name = nameRead[2],
            Num = numRead[2]
        }
    });
```

If you want even more control over how the data is returned, check the `Newtonsoft.JSON` library, which is de-facto the default in C# and provides all of the classes you mentioned. Its documentation is very good with many examples, so you should be able to find what you need in there.